# cross-domain jquery.ajax calls are getting aborted before sending requests to cross-domain server

Tags: jquery, cross-domain

We are using jquery.ajax() to run cross domain ajax calls. Sometimes we observed that these ajax calls were getting aborted and its http requests were not sent to cross-domain server. When ajax calls are aborted at the browser side, there were no error message noted. Could you please let us know on why ajax calls are getting aborted before sending requests to server and also please let us know to catch and resend aborted requests? 
Please let us know if you need more details.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The most common approach is to use your server as aproxy. You will send request to your server, your server will issue request to remote server and then grab result response. Then after processing response from remote server on your server you can easly send response back to your client.

If you are php user this can be easly achieved with curl: http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php, http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/techniques-and-resources-for-mastering-curl/

Comment: Reason for sending requests from browser to cross-domain server is remote user needs to be authenticated to cross-domain server to run some privileged commands. If we send requests via proxy server, could you let us know on how to make proxy server impersonate as remote user?